# inline variable is initialized more than once

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17, compiler-bug, inline-variable

Im seeing some examples of `inline const` variable getting initialized (and destructed) 3 times with visual studio 2017. Is this is a bug with the linker ? or is this supposed to happend in some other way ?

linker Comdat folding is set to Off.

Example Code:

```
#pragma once

struct A {
  A() {
    static int count = 0;
    ++count;
    ASSERT(count == 1);
  }
  ~A() {
  }
};


inline const A a = A();
```

In my solution, I have the assert fire twice (A constructor called 3 times).
Inspecting the call stack shows all call stacks are identical and all calls come from dynamic initializer for a(). Now I know for a fact this class is not used in other parts of the solution since I just created it to investigate this issue.

Im using VS17 15.8.9

Update: Bug report here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/297876/static-inline-variable-gets-destroyed-multiple-tim.html (you may upvote to help push for the bugfix)

Comment: Can we get a [mcve]?  Unless it is a compiler bug there should only be one instance created.

Comment: I suspect it could be bug in the linker (or compiler) yes

Comment: Doesn't happen with cl v19.16.26926

Comment: i get only one instance created when using g++ 8.2.1 and clang++ 6.0.1 with `-std=c++17` too. Surprisingly, I get only one instance in VS17 15.8.8 too :-) I'll see if I can upgrade to 15.8.9 and test it there.

Comment: Just upgraded to 15.8.9 and I stilll only get one instance from the code you''ve shown.

Comment: Debug or release build?

Comment: Just commented your answer :-)

Comment: ...but I just switched to a clean debug build and still got one instance.

Comment: @PeterRuderman I only noticed it in debug - as you seem to have found out it appears its not an issue in release.

Comment: @TedLyngmo just to be sure, did you include the code in multiple translation units ?

Comment: I found at least one person that seem to have filed the bug MSVC team already: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/297876/static-inline-variable-gets-destroyed-multiple-tim.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be an MSVC bug.  I'm able to reproduce it with the code below (also with VS2017 15.8.9).  Interestingly, I can only reproduce with a Debug build.  In Release mode, the optimizer seems to save us.

**Common.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo()
  {
    std::cout << "Constructing a Foo" << std::endl;
  }

  ~Foo()
  {
    std::cout << "Destructing a Foo" << std::endl;
  }
};

inline Foo const Bar;
```

**other.cpp**

```
#include "common.h"

void DoOtherStuff()
{
  std::cout << &Bar << std::endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "common.h"

void DoStuff()
{
  std::cout << &Bar << std::endl;
}

extern void DoOtherStuff();

int main()
{
  DoStuff();
  DoOtherStuff();
}
```

**Output (Debug)**

```
Constructing a Foo
Constructing a Foo
00007FF74FD50170
00007FF74FD50170
Destructing a Foo
Destructing a Foo
```

Comment: Wow ... I went for a release build directly :-)

Comment: This has been fixed in MSVC 2019. Corresponding closed bug report is [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/185559/debugger-called-twice.html); I've actually checked that I no longer get crashes in my own app, so I can confirm this.

Answer (score 4):

I get the bug in both debug and release (/Ox) mode using the MS C++ compiler version 19.16 (comes with, e.g., Visual Studio 15.9.4).

**Inline.Hpp**

```
#include <iostream>  
inline struct Foo  
{ Foo() { std::cout << "Constructing a Foo at " << this << std::endl; } }  
Instance;
```

**Inline.cpp**

```
#include "Inline.Hpp"  
int main() { return 0; }
```

**Inline2.cpp**

```
#include "Inline.Hpp"
```

After compiling and linking inline.cpp and inline2.cpp, the output on running is:

```
Constructing a Foo at 00BE4028  
Constructing a Foo at 00BE4028
```

The compiler and linker correctly resolve the two inline definitions to a single object, but incorrectly call the constructor for each definition, instead of just once. This is a serious bug which renders the "inline variable" feature of C++17 unusable.  The "workaround" is to regard inline variables as still unsupported by MS C++ as of version 19.16, even when the /std:c++17 switch is used.

Comment: Indeed - it's a very big issue with using the feature at all. You may upvote the bug report here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/297876/static-inline-variable-gets-destroyed-multiple-tim.html

Answer (score 3):

As of today there is an update for visual studio 2017 to version [15.9.24](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.9.24) which fixes the problem.

From the release notes:

> Fixed C++ compiler bug for proper folding of inline variable dynamic
>   initializers.

Comment: That is great news

Comment: Maybe it would be good that you edit the first post so that people know they can fix this issue by updating.

Comment: when we update, we seem to now get linker error instead with multiple symbols ? it that how it is supposed to be fixed because then its not so nice.. ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have redefinition or something?

Comment: We are investigating the issue still (it does not have a high priority yet), will update once we know more.