# Crash on inline global variable in header included multiple times

Tags: c++, global-variables, c++17, inline

I have a question about inline behavior of global variables in c++17, they do not seem to work as I understand. A simple program crashes on exit.

Making the variable extern instead of inline and defining it in a .cpp file solves the issue, but i'm wondering why it happens in the first place.

Can someone explain why the following gives an exception?

SomeSharedInclude.h

```
#pragma once
#include <unordered_set>

namespace Stuff
{
inline std::unordered_set<int> global_set;
}
```

main.cpp

```
##include "SomeSharedInclude.h"

int main() {}
```

OtherSource.cpp

```
##include "SomeSharedInclude.h"

class Test {};
```

Upon the program exiting the following happens:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation. _Pnode was 0xDDDDDDDD
```

Top of Call Stack:

```
TestGlobalInline.exe!std::list<int,std::allocator<int> >::clear() Line 1392
TestGlobalInline.exe!std::list<int,std::allocator<int> >::_Tidy() Line 1775
TestGlobalInline.exe!std::list<int,std::allocator<int> >::~list<int,std::allocator<int> >() Line 983
TestGlobalInline.exe!std::_Hash<std::_Uset_traits<int,std::_Uhash_compare<int,std::hash<int>,std::equal_to<int> >,std::allocator<int>,0> >::~_Hash<std::_Uset_traits<int,std::_Uhash_compare<int,std::hash<int>,std::equal_to<int> >,std::allocator<int>,0> >()
TestGlobalInline.exe!std::unordered_set<int,std::hash<int>,std::equal_to<int>,std::allocator<int> >::~unordered_set<int,std::hash<int>,std::equal_to<int>,std::allocator<int> >()
TestGlobalInline.exe!Stuff::`dynamic atexit destructor for 'global_set''()
ucrtbased.dll!54205f52()
```

---

This is on Visual Studio Community 15.9.7

I have tried other types for the global variable like std::{string, vector, stack}, so far only the unordered_set, unordered_map, and list crash.

---

Okay it seems to be a Visual Studio bug, where destructors are called multiple times for the global inline variables, and these classes (std::unordered_set etc) give an exception when that happens (the others like std::vector do not i checked).

Comment: Why are you defining variables in a header file?

Comment: @735Tesla `inline` variables is new in the C++17 standard, and allows multiple definitions of the variable in different translation units. See e.g. [this `inline` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) for details.

Comment: Your inline variable is a `std::unordered_set`, the error mentions `std::list`, that you don't show or mention. I suspect you misdiagnosed the inline variable as a culprit. Try to produce a [mcve], for yours and ours sake.

Comment: The std::unordered_set uses the std::list in the implementation. The code i have given is literally all it takes to produce the error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Microsoft implementation of the standard library, but somehow I find it hard to believe.

Comment: Instead of only showing the top of the call-stack, please show the full call-stack.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks! I'd still question whether it's good practice to use global variables in that way but that's pretty interesting.

Comment: @StoryTeller Me neither, but presumably unordered_set is a hash table and each bucket is a linked list .

Comment: @john - Even then, `std::list` has a bunch of constraints on it as a standard library container. I'd have imagined the unordered_set implementation to use a lower level implementation detail, rather than the public interface. Just seems weird, not that I don't believe the OP.

Comment: @StoryTeller Just checked and it seems that MS `std::unordered_set` uses a single `std::list` for all the elements. The hash table is a `std::vector` of iterators to that list.

Comment: @john - mmm. Given all of the above, I think the OP is seeing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53196700/inline-variable-is-initialized-more-than-once - MSVC is being buggy.

Comment: @Aedoro: Could reproduce the problem. Using `std::list` also crashes.

Comment: @Aedoro: Bugs reported: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/169305/vc2017-1552-inline-variable-crashed.html and there are others too. But not anything with `unordered_set`.

Comment: I'd raise a new bug, the set does seem to get destructed twice